# mixed effects model with crossed and nested effects (lme4)

Tags: r, mixed-model

I need some help with a mixed effects model in R. I want to know if there is any effect of month on home range size. The following is my set-up and an idea of how it is laid out in an excel sheet: I have 2 parks that I have home range estimates from (labeled parks 1 and 2). There are 6 individuals in each park (individuals 1-6 in park 1 and individuals 7-12 in park 2). There are 2 years worth of data (years 1 and 2), so for each month, each individual should have two home range estimates (one for year 1 and one for year 2).

I know "ID" should be a random effect, and I currently have "park","year", and "month" as fixed effects. My first thought is that "Park", "year" and "month" should all be crossed, but I am lost as to what to do with "ID"?

I have the following in R:

```
lme4(Homerangesize~(park/year/month)+(1/ID))
```

How do i "fix" this bit of code so that it represents my experimental set up? Am I correct in having park, month, and year crossed effects? Should ID be nested?

Comment: sorry to be fussy, but: Since this is an ecological question, I think you don't really want to "test whether there is an effect of month on home range size". You know there **is** variation in home range size across months (more or less all effects in ecology are non-zero). The question is how big it is and whether you can distinguish it from noise or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

```
lmer(Homerangesize~park*year*month+(1|ID),
      contrasts=list(park="contr.sum",year="contr.sum",month="contr.sum"),
      data=your_data)
```

makes sense.  That estimates the full three-way interaction between park, year, and month as fixed effects, but uses sum-to-zero contrasts so that the reported *main effect* of month is the average across all park $\times$ year combinations.

You should in principle also allow for the variation in among-year/among-month variation in home ranges per individual, e.g.

```
Homerangesize~park*year*month+(1|ID)+(1|ID:month)+(1|ID:year)
```

although this model might be slightly more complex than you can fit with your data.